# How can we create menu in oracle report 10 g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report

I want to create a menu in oracle report 10g.
Tell me how i can do it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a UI component for the user to pick a report from? If so, I'd recommend building an Oracle Form to present a list of reports to the user, which will invoke the report selected by the user.